# Earth Engine, how to convert 0 pixel values to transparent or nodata?

Tags: google-earth-engine, masking, null, image-segmentation

I'm using the following snippet to convert `canny edges` to black and white to highlight boundaries. However, I want to fill the black area with `transparent or NODATA`, is there a way to do this in EE?

```
var final_stacked_canny = ee.Algorithms.CannyEdgeDetector({
  image: final_stacked, threshold: 0.7
}).multiply(255);

var perimeterPixelsCanny = final_stacked_canny.select(1).neq(final_stacked_canny.select(0)).rename('perimeter')
Map.addLayer(perimeterPixelsCanny, {}, "Canny On CCCI + GOSAVI + EVI", false)
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`gt()` and `selfMask()` on the canny edge image will do the trick. Use for the `gt()` value the same value as you use in the threshold argument for the CannyEdgeDetector:

```
var canny = ee.Algorithms.CannyEdgeDetector({
  image: image.select('B5'), threshold: threshold
});

// mask everything but the edges
var cannyMasked = canny.gt(threshold) // edges will be 1, everything else 0
                      .selfMask() // to mask every pixel which eq 0
```

See [here](https://code.earthengine.google.com/c456201a4fdeea98eb816ce337a132ba) a simplified example